# Prove or disprove if $|G|=|K|\neq1$ then the direct product $|G|\times|K|$ will never be a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

$$\gcd(|G|,|K|) = |G|=|K|\ne1$$
$$|G\times K|=|G||K|=|G|^{2}=|K|^{2}$$
$$G\times K =\{(g,k):g\in G,k\in K\}$$
I need to find if $$\:\exists\:(g,k)^{|G|^2}\in G\times K$$
I can't use: if G and H are cyclic groups whose orders are relatively prime, then G × H is cyclic as well.
Thanks.

Comment: If you write $\;|G|\times |K|\;$ you are multiplying, or something, **two numbers**. The direct product of two groups $\;G,H\;$ is denoted $\;G\times H\;$, so what exactly did you mean? That the numbers $\;|G|, |K|\;$ are different from one, or that **the groups** $\;G,K\;$ are non -trivial??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the group $H = G \times K$. Then if $\mid G \mid = \mid K \mid = n \not = 1$, the group $H$ has order $n^2$. But it's fairly easy to notice that each element of $H$ has an order dividing $n$. Therefore as no element has the same order as the group, the group can't be cyclic.

Comment: Why each element of H has an order dividing $n$ ?
if $a\in H: o(a)|o(H)\\o(H)=n^{2}$

Comment: @Asaf Note that an element of $H$ is of the form $(a,b)$, where $a \in G, b \in K$. Then $o((a,b)) = \text{LCM}(o(a),o(b))$. But we know that $o(a) \mid o(G) = n$ and $o(b) \mid o(K) = n$. Therefore $\text{LCM}(o(a),o(b)) \mid n$. From this we conclude that $o((a,b)) \le n$